# WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1494943588964_0010_01_000001 is : 143

Tags: hadoop

I have setup hadoop 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 in standalone mode. 
I have installed Hive 2.1.1 and working on HQL.
Most of the queries triggers MR jobs. 
when i run queries which triggers MR jobs, system automatically gets logged out by terminating all the processes.
When i check the log of Node Manager, i can see the statement which lead to the problem is,

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1494943588964_0010_01_000001 is : 143
2017-05-16 19:48:08,263 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2017-05-16 19:48:08,297 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1494943588964_0010_01_000002 is : 143
2017-05-16 19:48:08,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1494943588964_0010_01_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
```

And in common the log files contains the statement:

```
RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

Please find the properties set in yarn-site.xml:

```
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services = mapreduce_shuffle
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 6144
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 2048
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 6144 
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb = 1024
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts = -Xmx819m
```

can anybody help on this..

Answer (score 0):

RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
could be due to a couple of reasons, a user might kill the app or might container reached it's capacity resources.

Comment: It's a comment to the question. If you are not sure with your answer, you can post in a comment after gaining minimum required reputation.